# Configure tomcat to use Java 9 native OCSP stapling and OCSP check

Tags: java, tomcat9, ocsp

How can I configure Apache Tomcat to use OCSP stapling and certificate revocation check using OCSP implementation available in Java 9?

Is running tomcat 9 on Java 9 with following property is enough?

```java
// Enable OCSP Stapling (off by default)
System.setProperty(“jdk.tls.server.enableStatusRequestExtension”, “true”);
```

I have tried above but doesn't seem to be working

Comment: You're tried that code where? System properties should generally be set using the `-D` JVM switch, to ensure the value is always available. You probably set the value *after* the JVM has already looked for it.

Comment: Yes I have tried both ways in my Springboot application using -D option as well as setting up the system property before calling SpringApplication.run method but didn't work

Comment: Did you try configuring Tomcat as [documented](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Configuring_OCSP_Connector)?

Comment: @Andreas this documentation only talks about verifying OCSP responses from client certificates, and will not staple any OCSP responses to the outgoing cert. Also even though the document you referenced does say this will enable OCSP, there is no indication it would so in 'SSL support" of "Configuration Reference" document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this [Infotiate SSL](https://github.com/infotiate/sslproxy/blob/1.0/README.md) Proxy project on git hub. We had similar use case and this SSL proxy answers most of what we needed to do regarding more control over the certificate path validation process in Spring-boot application

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I saw they are using Zuul pre-filter and similar thing I was trying to do with Servlet filter. I was in the impression that Java native implementation will do the OCSP checking in case of client certificate provided by the client during TLS MA handshake however it seems that's not the case and we'll have to do it via a custom code. I believe Java documentation should provide more clarity on this.